# Android launches an async task on every configuration change

Tags: android, configuration, android-asynctask

After reading a few articles about Android configuration, I still don't know how to NOT launch an async task when I change the view from portrait to landscape. I load some information from the server, and it will be not wise to load it every time I rotate my phone. I want to load it once. Can I do that without adding 'changeConfig' flag in Manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Make your AsyncTask a private instance variable of your class (has to be declared as a static inner class or as a separate file).

2 Return your AsyncTask instance in `onRetainConfigurationChanges()`

```
  public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
      return yourAsyncTask;
  }
```

3 Retrieve it in `oResume()`:

```
 public void onResume() {
   Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
   if (data != null) {
     ... // pass in your activity to the AsyncTask so it can update your views
   } else {
     ... // create new AsyncTask and spin it up.
   }
 }
```

Comment: As the activity is destroyed every time I change the configuration, shouldn't I retrieve the data in onCreate()?

Comment: Right. For answer brevity I put it in the onResume since that is probably where you want to create the new AsyncTask, but you're right, the getLastNonConfigurationInstance() should go in the `onCreate()`

Comment: Heh. I stuck in '// pass in your activity...' I pass it, but my list view is not updated. I can't see any elements on it. Seems like AsyncTask is just killed....

Comment: OK, now it's fine. I didn't even have to make it static ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

This will solve all the issues ur mentioning

Basically u need to implement

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
```

which returns the data you want

and then you need to call getLastNonConfigurationInstance and if the value is there, not get it from server :-)

Comment: Thank You. Now I know what to do ;)

Comment: `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` has been deprecated. Use `setRetainInstance(boolean)` in the Fragment class instead

Answer (score 0):

Don't blindly launch an asyncTask. Follow these instructions:

1. define 'boolean guard = false' in your activity variables declaration
2. inside "onCreate(...) do:

   ```
   if(savedInstanceState!=null){
       guard=(Boolean) savedInstanceState.get(guardkey) //guardkey is the bundle key. (*1)
   } else{
       guard=false;
   }
   if(!guard){
       //launch your asyncTask
       guard=true;
       //other operations if needed
   }
   ```

   now, add to "onSaveInstanceState(outState)" method you have (if you don't have it, do so now) the following line:

   ```
   outState.put(guardkey, guard); //(*1)
   ```

NOTE: this prevents you to fire tasks every time you change configurations. It presumes that you have already received your info from the server, and you saved it in your activity properly (this means you can retrieve it on activity restart). Otherwise, this solution is not for you.